# UNIX grepping the latest version of files in a install log

Tags: regex, unix, grep, command

I want to grab the latest version of the files, from the log file and output to a new file using unix command.

This is an example of the logfile.

patches.txt

```
Wed Jan 15 10:42:26 MYT 2014, Start, SPIRTE_4.3.2.B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:42:28 MYT 2014, End, TILES_7.3.66B1, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:35 MYT 2014, End, MOVIES_OPENING_4.3.2.B1, FAILED
Wed Jan 15 10:42:36 MYT 2014, Start, MOVEMENT_7.3.68B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:42:36 MYT 2014, Start, MOBS_7.3.2B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:42:37 MYT 2014, End, TILES_7.3.68B1, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:38 MYT 2014, Start, MOVIES_CUTSCENE_4.3.2.57B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:42:38 MYT 2014, Start, GAME_4.3.2.57B1_SERVER, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:42:43 MYT 2014, End, GAME_4.2.57B2_CLIENT, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:43 MYT 2014, End, GAME_4.2.57B4_SERVER, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:45 MYT 2014, End, GAME_4.2.57B1_CLIENT, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:45 MYT 2014, End, GAME_4.2.57B1_SERVER, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:45 MYT 2014, End, DB_4.2.57C2_CLIENT, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:45 MYT 2014, End, DB_4.2.57C2_SERVER, DONE
```

1.The latest date of a file specifies the latest version, e.g

```
Wed Jan 15 10:42:26 MYT 2014, Start, SPIRTE_4.3.2.B1, DONE
Wed Jan 16 10:42:26 MYT 2014, Start, SPIRTE_4.3.2.B1, DONE //latest
Wed Jan 17 10:42:26 MYT 2014, Start, SPIRTE_4.3.2.B1, FAILED //does not consider
```

2.DONE at the end of the line specifies that the patch is installed.

3.Every file has this format [characters_][versionNumber_][CLIENT/SERVER], the [CLIENT/SERVER] is not mandatory.

4.If multiple version of a file is installed, the latest one will overwrites the previous one. e.g

```
Wed Jan 15 10:42:37 MYT 2014, End, TILES_7.3.68B1, DONE //overwritten
Wed Jan 16 10:45:37 MYT 2014, End, TILES_7.3.70C1, DONE //latest
```

5.A file with the suffix of _CLIENT consider a different file with the suffix of _SERVER even though they start with the same name (but still bounds to rule #4).
Take this for example:

```
Wed Jan 15 10:39:23 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7_3_2_3B1_Client, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:45 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.57B1, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:41:39 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.42B4, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:41:38 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.33B3, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:39:34 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.1B1, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:39:07 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.ServicePackB1, DONE
```

`GAME_TILES_7_3_2_3B1_Client` is one file.

`GAME_TILES_7.3.2.33B3` is another file.

`GAME_TILES_7.3.2.1B1` is the same as `GAME_TILES_7.3.2.33B3` and also `GAME_TILES_7.3.2.ServicePackB1`

e.g of output file

```
Wed Jan 15 10:42:37 MYT 2014, End, TILES_7.3.68B1, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:45 MYT 2014, End, GAME_4.2.57B1_CLIENT, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:45 MYT 2014, End, GAME_4.2.57B1_SERVER, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:45 MYT 2014, End, DB_4.2.57C2_CLIENT, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:45 MYT 2014, End, DB_4.2.57C2_SERVER, DONE
```

Strategy:

```
1. sort all the files
2. grep all the lines that has DONE
3. check for rule #4 and rule #5 (how? I can't use tail for this)
```

Where I am now :  grep '.* DONE' < patches.txt |sort

TEST FILE:

```
Wed Jan 15 10:36:16 MYT 2014, StartInstall, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2B188, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:36:21 MYT 2014, StartInstall, GAME_TILES_7.3.2B467, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:36:21 MYT 2014, StartInstall, GAME_TILES_7.3.2B467, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:37:33 MYT 2014, EndInstall, GAME_TILES_7.3.2B467, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:37:35 MYT 2014, StartInstall, MOVIE_CUTSCENE_4.3.2B246, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:37:35 MYT 2014, StartInstall, MOVIE_CUTSCENE_4.3.2B246, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:38:21 MYT 2014, EndInstall, MOVIE_CUTSCENE_4.3.2B246, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:38:59 MYT 2014, EndInstall, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2B188, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:39:00 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.ServicePackB1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:39:00 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.ServicePackB1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:39:07 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.ServicePackB1, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:39:08 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7_3_2_3B1_Server, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:39:08 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7_3_2_3B1_Server, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:39:16 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7_3_2_3B1_Server, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:39:16 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7_3_2_3B1_Client, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:39:16 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7_3_2_3B1_Client, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:39:23 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7_3_2_3B1_Client, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:39:24 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.1B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:39:24 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.1B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:39:34 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.1B1, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:39:35 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.1B1_simulator, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:39:35 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.1B1_simulator, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:39:45 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.1B1_simulator, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:39:46 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOVIE_CUTSCENE_4.3.2.1B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:39:46 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOVIE_CUTSCENE_4.3.2.1B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:39:53 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOVIE_CUTSCENE_4.3.2.1B1, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:39:54 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.1B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:39:54 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.1B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:40:03 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.1B1, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:40:04 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.2B1_Server, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:40:04 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.2B1_Server, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:40:12 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.2B1_Server, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:40:13 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.2B1_Client, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:40:13 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.2B1_Client, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:40:21 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.2B1_Client, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:40:22 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.4B2, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:40:22 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.4B2, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:40:32 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.4B2, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:40:33 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.2B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:40:33 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.2B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:40:42 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.2B1, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:40:43 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOVIE_CUTSCENE_4.3.2.2B3, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:40:43 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOVIE_CUTSCENE_4.3.2.2B3, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:40:50 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOVIE_CUTSCENE_4.3.2.2B3, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:40:51 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.12B2, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:40:51 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.12B2, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:40:51 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.12B2, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:40:52 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.23B2, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:40:52 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.23B2, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:40:52 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.23B2, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:40:53 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.13B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:40:53 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.13B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:07 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.13B1, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:41:07 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.17B3, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:07 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.17B3, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:08 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.17B3, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:41:09 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.30B4, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:09 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.30B4, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:09 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.30B4, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:41:10 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.41B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:10 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.41B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:10 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.41B1, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:41:11 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.13B2, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:11 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.13B2, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:26 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.13B2, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:41:27 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.16B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:27 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.16B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:29 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.16B1, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:41:30 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.22B2, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:30 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.22B2, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:30 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.22B2, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:41:31 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.24B2, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:31 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.24B2, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:31 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.24B2, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:41:32 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.25B2, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:32 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.25B2, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:32 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.25B2, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:41:33 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.28B2, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:33 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.28B2, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:33 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.28B2, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:41:34 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.40B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:34 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.40B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:34 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.40B1, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:41:35 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.43B2, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:35 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.43B2, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:36 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.43B2, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:41:36 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.32B5, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:36 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.32B5, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:37 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.32B5, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:41:37 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.33B3, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:37 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.33B3, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:38 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.33B3, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:41:39 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.42B4, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:39 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.42B4, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:39 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.42B4, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:41:40 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.62B1_Server, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:40 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.62B1_Server, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:51 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.62B1_Server, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:41:53 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.62B1_Client, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:41:53 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.62B1_Client, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:42:02 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.62B1_Client, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:03 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOVIE_CUTSCENE_4.3.2.15B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:42:03 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOVIE_CUTSCENE_4.3.2.15B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:42:12 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOVIE_CUTSCENE_4.3.2.15B1, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:12 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.32B7, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:42:12 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.32B7, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:42:23 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.32B7, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:24 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.66B4, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:42:24 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.66B4, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:42:25 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.66B4, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:26 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.55B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:42:26 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.55B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:42:35 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.55B1, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:36 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.68B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:42:36 MYT 2014, StartPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.68B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:42:37 MYT 2014, EndPatch, GAME_TILES_7.3.2.68B1, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:38 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.57B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:42:38 MYT 2014, StartPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.57B1, OK
Wed Jan 15 10:42:45 MYT 2014, EndPatch, MOB_CHARACTER_4.3.2.57B1, DONE
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this only with bash, or at least not efficiently, what you need is a hashmap/dictionary data structure which to my knowledge bash lacks of, you can implement a really simple python script to do this with a dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, here's *one* way to do it:

```
awk '$9 == "DONE" { key = $8; add = ""; sub ("_CLIENT,$",",",key); if (key != $8) { add = "_CLIENT," } else { sub ("_SERVER,$",",",key); if (key != $8) { add = "_SERVER," } } sub ("_[^_]*$", "", key); key = key""add; assoc[key] = $0; } END { for (var in assoc) { print assoc[var] } }' inputFile.txt
```

Now that's pretty ugly, so I'll break it down and add comments so you can hopefully understand how it works:

```
$9 == "DONE" {                        // Only want "DONE" lines.
    key = $8;                         // Get the key.
    add = ""                          // Save client/server/none and remove
    sub ("_CLIENT,$", ",", key);
    if (key != $8) {
        add = "_CLIENT,"
    } else {
        sub ("_SERVER,$", ",", key);  
        if (key != $8) {
            add = "_SERVER,"
        }
    }
    sub ("_[^_]*$", "", key);         // Remove version.
    key = key""add;                   // Put client/server/none back.
    assoc[key] = $0;                  // Store line.
}
END {
    for (var in assoc) {              // Print out every keyed line.
        print assoc[var]
    }
}
```

To be honest, once `awk` scripts get this complicated, you're better off putting them into a `script.awk` file and running that with `awk -f` - doing these long scripts on the command line is a bit of a pain.

The trick here is the use of the key calculation and associative array. Removing the version from field 8 means that it becomes an effective key for the "feature", such as `GAME_SERVER` or `TILES_`.

The way in which this is done is as follows:

- The `sub` command replaces the first argument (`_CLIENT,$` means `_CLIENT,` at the end of the line) with the second (just the comma) in the given variable (`key`).
- We first try client - if the substitution worked, `key` is now different to `$8` and we save that fact and don't worry about checking for server.
- If there was no client, we try server. If found, we store *that* fact and carry on. If neither client nor server was found, we keep the original state that there is nothing to add back to the key.
- Now we have a string with just the version at the end (but we remember whether it had client, server or nothing at the end originally). The `sub` to remove the version simply gets rid of everything after (and including) the final `_` character.
- Then we add back the client or server string and that's our key - the original `$8` but with the version removed.

Setting the associative array value for that key will then either create a new entry or overwrite the current entry, meaning that later lines in the file with the same key will override the previous ones.

Then, at the end, you simply iterate over the associative array, outputting the values (the lines from the input file). On my system, you see:

```
Wed Jan 15 10:42:37 MYT 2014, End, TILES_7.3.68B1, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:45 MYT 2014, End, DB_4.2.57C2_CLIENT, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:45 MYT 2014, End, DB_4.2.57C2_SERVER, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:45 MYT 2014, End, GAME_4.2.57B1_CLIENT, DONE
Wed Jan 15 10:42:45 MYT 2014, End, GAME_4.2.57B1_SERVER, DONE
```

as desired.

Comment: +1 for effort, but as far as I concern, the code does not solve rule #5, I will provide a test log file for you to test. Also note that the file name might be MOVIES_OPENING_4.3.2.B1 and MOVIES_CUTSCENE_4.3.2.57B1, so using the first bit, which is MOVIES is not the way to go.

Comment: @McKevin, it _does_ solve rule #5 which states the client/server are to be considered different files. As to the possibility of `_` showing up in places _other_ than the separator areas, I'll amend the answer.

Comment: @McKevin: okay, it now handles cases where there are extraneous `_` characters. The `_server/_client` bit _must_ be at the end (if it exists) and no `_` characters are allowed in the version.

Comment: Thanks, can you please also explain this line? sub ("_CLIENT,$", ",", key);
    if (key != $8) {